# Manage and build Url/strings from a collection of substrings (aka build request urls)

Tags: android, string, url, networking, kotlin

I have following groups of string and would like to create a string following the syntax: substr1.substr2.substr3 = substr1 + substr2 + substr3

```
data class Protocol( val http: String = "http://",
                     val https: String = "https://")

data class BaseUrl( val baseProd: String = "url_prod",
                    val baseDev: String = "url_dev",
                    val baseTest: String = "url_test")

data class ApiEndpoint( val GET_USER: String = "endpoint_get_user",
                        val LOGIN: String = "endpoint_login",
                        val REGISTER: String = "endpoint_get",
                        val FETCH_HISTORY: String = "endpoint_fetch_history")

data class WebUrl( val HOME: String = "path_home",
                   val BALANCE: String = "path_balance",
                   val MANAGE_SUBSCRIPTION: String = "path_manage_subscription")

data class RequestEnvironment( val mobile: String = "query_mobile",
                               val desktop: String = "query_desktop")
```

My goal is to make something that build the strings like this

```
UrlFactory.https.baseDev.GET_USER     //result: https://url_dev/get_user
UrlFactory.https.baseProd.HOME.mobile //result: https://url_prod/home?mobile=1
UrlFactory.http.baseDev.BALANCE       //result: http://url_dev/balance
```

Have anyone built a nice way to handle url strings dynamically like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an object `Url` which is in charge of building up your URL string.

You can build up Url by passing in your selected options through the constructor.

When the object is constructed, you can then call `toString` which will concatenate and return the values together.

```
class Url ( var protocol : Protocol, 
           var baseUrl : BaseUrl, 
           var apiEndpoint : ApiEndpoint, 
           var webUrl : WebUrl, 
           var requestEnvironment : RequestEnvironment) {

    override fun toString() : String {
        return protocol.value + 
            baseUrl.value + 
            apiEndpoint.value + 
            webUrl.value + 
            requestEnvironment.value
    }
}
```

To add another level of safety when working with your Strings, I took the liberty of converting them to enums. This will give you the benefit of allowing you to limit the possible values which can be set:

```
enum class Protocol(val value : String) {
    HTTP("http://"),
    HTTPS("https://")
}

enum class BaseUrl(val value : String) {
    BASE_PROD("url_prod"),
    BASE_DEV("url_dev"),
    BASE_TEST("url_test")
}

enum class ApiEndpoint(val value : String) {
    GET_USER("endpoint_get_user"),
    LOGIN("endpoint_login"),
    REGISTER("endpoint_get"),
    FETCH_HISTORY("endpoint_fetch_history")
}

enum class WebUrl(val value : String) {
    HOME("path_home"),
    BALANCE("path_balance"),
    MANAGE_SUBSCRIPTION("path_manage_subscription")
}

enum class RequestEnvironment(val value : String) {
    MOBILE("query_mobile"),
    DESKTOP("query_desktop")
}
```

Finally, here is an example of how you can now build your URL:

```
fun main() {

    val url : Url = Url(Protocol.HTTP, 
                        BaseUrl.BASE_DEV, 
                        ApiEndpoint.GET_USER, 
                        WebUrl.HOME,
                        RequestEnvironment.MOBILE);

    println(url.toString())
}
```

Comment: I actually used Enum before I tried to remodel it with structs/ data classes.
When googleing "Enum android" the first result is an article titled "Android Performance: Avoid using ENUM on Android" by Ankit Sinhal.
This is what led me to the conclution Enum was to be avoided at all costs.
Can you do this without the Enums?

article: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3

Comment: @JoelBroström I think [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7so7ne/you_should_strictly_avoid_using_enums_on_android/) is a good discussion of that post. To summarise, it's the decision between maintainability and readability, or a _slight_ performance optimisation (a matter of kilobytes) Up to you, I can update to not use enums if necessary

Comment: Never have I been so glad to stand corrected!
Would it not be that I spent 2 hours refactoring my Enum code I would be jumping in excitement.